# Flutter FCM exception `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService`

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, build.gradle

I am trying to implement the `firebase_messaging` for push notifications in my flutter application. i have written cloud function which gets triggered whenever a new document is added to a firebase collection & then it sends the notification to the userTokens that have been stored in the firebase.

Right now i am checking with a test notification from firebase to my device but when i try to send the test notification, it terminates the application & throws this exception in the terminal.

```
D/FLTFireMsgReceiver( 9534): broadcast received for message
W/mycents.mycent( 9534): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(I)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/mycents.mycent( 9534): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(ILjava/lang/String;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/mycents.mycent( 9534): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->size()I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/mycents.mycent( 9534): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->get(I)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/mycents.mycent( 9534): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->getName(I)Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/mycents.mycent( 9534): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->isEmpty()Z (greylist-max-o, reflection, denied)
D/AndroidRuntime( 9534): Shutting down VM
I/QarthLog( 9534): [PatchStore] createDisableExceptionQarthFile
I/QarthLog( 9534): [PatchStore] create disable file for com.mycents.mycents uid is 10501
E/flutter ( 9534): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/dart_runtime_hooks.cc(38)] Dart Error: Class 'NotificationHandler' not found in library ''.E/flutter ( 9534): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(89)] Dart Error: Class 'NotificationHandler' not found in library ''.       
E/AndroidRuntime( 9534): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 9534): Process: com.mycents.mycents, PID: 9534
E/AndroidRuntime( 9534): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mycents.mycents-lT2te_dukA36VqOn_hbhoQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mycents.mycents-lT2te_dukA36VqOn_hbhoQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.mycents.mycents-lT2te_dukA36VqOn_hbhoQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /hw_product/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime( 9534):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4796)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9534):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3000(ActivityThread.java:260)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9534):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2470)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9534):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9534):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9534):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8676)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9534):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9534):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9534):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1109)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9534): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mycents.mycents-lT2te_dukA36VqOn_hbhoQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mycents.mycents-lT2te_dukA36VqOn_hbhoQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.mycents.mycents-lT2te_dukA36VqOn_hbhoQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /hw_product/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime( 9534):        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:209)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9534):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9534):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9534):        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateService(AppComponentFactory.java:129)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9534):        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateService(CoreComponentFactory.java:75)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9534):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4791)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9534):        ... 8 more
E/flutter ( 9534): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(89)] Dart Error: Class 'NotificationHandler' not found in library ''.
I/Process ( 9534): Sending signal. PID: 9534 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

i think i have done the required configuration for FCM to work but still i might be doing something wrong.
Here is my code for handling background messages. the print statements are just for debugging.

```
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

import '../../routes/app_router.dart';

class NotificationHandler {
  static Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(
      RemoteMessage message) async {
    print("########################");
    print(message.data);
  }

  static void registerNotificationMethods() {
    print("******************************");
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
      print(message.data);
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      _handleMessage(message, openedApp: true);
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .getInitialMessage()
        .then((RemoteMessage? message) {
      if (message != null) {
        _handleMessage(message);
      }
    });
  }

  static void _handleMessage(RemoteMessage message, {bool openedApp = false}) {
    String? route = message.data['route'];
    if (route != null) {
      switch (route) {
        case '/product':
          AppRouter.pushNamed('/product');
          break;
        case 'cart':
          AppRouter.pushNamed('/cart');
          break;
        case 'profile':
          AppRouter.pushNamed('/profile');
          break;
        default:
          AppRouter.pushNamed('/home');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

& i'm calling it from `main.dart` file like this:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();
  NotificationHandler.registerNotificationMethods();
```

`firebase_messaging` package version:

```
firebase_messaging: ^14.6.6
```

i have got this in `android/gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

& also i've included this in app level gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.2.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:14.6.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.2.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

& i have included this to the android manifest file:

```
<service
            android:name="io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Can someone check & suggest, what i am doing wrong here?
Thank You!